# Haskell REST Service with Scotty: Convert JSON back to to Data

Tags: json, haskell, scotty

I built a REST Service with Haskell and Scotty and have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Main where

import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Aeson (FromJSON, ToJSON)
import Data.Text.Lazy
import GHC.Generics
import Web.Scotty

data Point = Point { x :: Int, y :: Int } deriving (Generic, Show)
instance ToJSON Point
instance FromJSON Point
movePoint :: Point -> Int -> Int -> Point
movePoint (Point x y) dx dy = Point (x + dx) (y + dy)

data Rectangle = Rectangle { width :: Int, height :: Int, point :: Point } deriving (Generic, Show)
instance ToJSON Rectangle
instance FromJSON Rectangle
move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle
move r@(Rectangle {point = p}) dx dy = r { point = movePoint p dx dy }

main = do
  putStrLn "Starting Server..."
  scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/rectangle/:id" $ do
      id <- param "id"      
      text id

    post "/rectangle" $ do
      rectangle <- jsonData :: ActionM Rectangle
      json rectangle    

    post "rectangle/move/:dx/:dy" $ do      
      dx <- param "dx"
      dy <- param "dy"
      rectangle <- jsonData :: ActionM Rectangle
      move rectangle dx dy
      json rectangle
```

When compiling i get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                                    Text IO a0'
                with actual type `Rectangle'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: move rectangle dx dy
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { dx <- param "dx";
            dy <- param "dy";
            rectangle <- jsonData :: ActionM Rectangle;
            move rectangle dx dy;
            .... }'
```

What am i missing? I would like to call the "move" function and then send the moved rectangle back...

Comment: `move` is just a regular function producing a `Rectange`, but you use it in a do block where an `ActionT Text IO` is required. I'm guess you wanted a let statment: `let newRectanlge = move ...`

Comment: yes this fixed the problem, thank you